# Modeling length of stay with (Cox) regression with censored observations

Tags: survival, cox-model, data-leakage

I'm attempting to model length of stay (LOS) in a psychiatric child/adolescent setting. My LOS is censored for a few patients because they are required to leave the facility when they turn 18.

I was pointed to Cox regression because the time to event model, and because it might deal with the censored data. During the modelling I wondered whether the age at admission might be used as a predictor. However, because this age is directly related to the censoring I'm feeling a little unsure about it. It kind of seems like it would introduce some data leakage?

I'd love some intuition or pointers on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you have complete data on entry and arrival ages/times for all those who left before they turned 18?

Comment: How many patients are censored at the age of 18?

Comment: Only around 10. But I'd also be curious what to do if a larger proportion of cases met that condition.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the mandatory discharge of 18-year-olds will create an inaccurate assessment of the association between age and time-to-discharge. Age results in removal from the dataset either as an event of interest or as a nonevent. The former is acceptable if discharge from aging is of interest under your research hypothesis. The latter prevents observation of the event of interest and is a form of dependent censoring, which must be addressed to test your hypothesis or to obtain meaningful associations.

Options:

1. Exclude patients who will age-out. If there are few exclusions and you have examples of patients who are nearly 18 with complete hospitalizations, you can obtain accurate estimates of time-to-discharge by excluding patients who will age-out.
2. Weight the analysis for patients who do not age-out. See: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0962280216628900